# str_replace not working with arabic string

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, arabic

I have the following string,in which  certain special patterns are used which needs to be replaced while displaying

```
// String 
if($lang==2){ // based on this condition $usrmsg string will switch b/w english or arabic

$usrmsg = "This is #1|.This is #2|";

}else{

 $usrmsg = "#هذا هو |3#. هذا هو |4 ";

}
```

**Replacement code**

I have used the following to replace the patterns from the string.

```
$rep_keys = array(0 => "#1|" ,1 => "#2|",2 => "#3|",3 => "#4|");

$rep_vals = array(0 => "demo1" ,1 => "demo2",2 => "تجريبي 2"<=3  ,"جريبي 1");

for($k=0;$k<count($rep_vals);$k++){
  if(strpos($usrmsg , $rep_keys[$k])!=""){
       $usrmsg = str_replace($rep_keys[$k],$rep_vals[$k],$usrmsg );
   }
}
```

This works fine with english string but its not working with arabic.
Can anyone help pls!!!!

Comment: You wouldn't need the loop btw. [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) accepts two arrays for search and replacement strings. Also show how your two code snippets interact. And lastly explain why you're not using [`gettext`](http://php.net/gettext) et al.

Comment: @mario both are in same page.The scenario is every time that string will be different,its created by user with that patterns using specific forms(both arabic and english).we will replace the patterns with user details stored in db and send.Can you please suggest some examples or tutorial for gettext

Comment: Your example string seems to contain a left-to-right marker. The display and binary representation are different. Anyway, use `preg_replace` with `/u` Unicode flag then.

Answer (score 0):

A fast (and simple) way to do that is to use [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$trans = array("#1|" => "demo1",
               "#2|" => "demo2",
               "#3|" => "جريبي 1",
               "#4|" => "تجريبي 2");

$str = "abc #1| 123 #2| def #3| 456 #4|";

echo strtr($str, $trans);
```

About arabic characters:

Some code editors have difficulty to manage RTL characters and in particular to represent them. It is possible that your code editor show something that is totally wrong. To ensure that your code is what you mean, I suggest to use a very basic code editor like nano.

Comment: Its not working am getting same result.#هذا هو |3#. هذا هو |4

Comment: @user3686534: works for me (tested). Try several editors to see how looks your code source, or better display it in a terminal: `cat yourfile.php`

Comment: Same problem whether I use strstr or str_replace, and I'm using vim. So it's something othe than the editor, it seems.